# Matplotlib Navigation Toolbar

Tags: navigation, matplotlib, toolbar

In mplot3d the default mouse functionality, rotates the plot.

In the navigation toolbar of matplotlib,  After I click on zoom (or pan), how do I restore it to the original default mouse functionality.

Am I missing something terribly silly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clicking the zoom (or pan) button again, restores it.

terribly silly - yes!